# Alternatives to WalletConnect on React native - to connect MetaMask blockchain wallet to React native app

Tags: react-native, ethereum, blockchain, metamask, decentralized-applications

I’m building a blockchain app on react native, and working with the WalletConnect package to connect a MetaMask wallet to my app, this has proven very challenge due to inconsistent documentation and dependency issues.

Is WalletConnect the best solution on react native, or is there a better solution anyone can recommend.
(Have done research but haven’t found concrete answer)

Thanks!

Have done research but haven’t found concrete answer for better alternatives to WalletConnect on react native.

Answer (score 0):

> Is WalletConnect the best solution on react native

Yes.

> this has proven very challenge due to inconsistent documentation and dependency issues

I suggest you join to WalletConnec developer Discord and ask support there.

Note that dozens of projects have successfully implemented WalletConnect on React Native.